# can we access the df from another notebook by using display(df) command?

Tags: na

I have two notebooks 1.bronze ,2.silver.
In bronze I have created student data frame as df.
I am trying to access the df in silver by using display(df).
It is showing error

I want to see the df in silver layer by using display(df).
Is it possible?